# assigning existing bones to vertex groups

Tags: rigging, bones

I have one model and it was separated by foot, head, hands, so on.. they had their own armature, I want to unite them under one armature, so I parented them under one armature and removed their own, the vertex groups are still there but bones are red, as you can see in the picture, looks like they are not connected to meshes, How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: you need to make sure that the vertex groups of your mesh have the same name as the bones so that the bones will be able to control them